# About matching rules for function templates. Why does std::cout<<"s" call not a member function of std::cout but a global function of std

Tags: c++, templates

In the case of:

```cpp
int a = 123;

std::cout << a;
/* invoked std::ostream& std::ostream::operator<<(int val) */

std::cout << &a;
/* invoked std::ostream::operator<<(const void* val) */
```

However, in the case of:

```cpp
std::cout << "hello\n";
/* invoked std::ostream& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char>>(
    std::ostream& ostr, const void* val) */
```

Why not invoke `std::ostream& std::ostream::operator<<(const void* val)`?

---

My initial assumption was that `std::cout.operator<<("hello\n");` would output "hello," but it actually printed an address.

```cpp
int main()
{
    std::cout << "hello\n";
    std::operator<<(std::cout, "hello\n");
    std::cout.operator<<("hello\n");
    /*  output:
        hello
        hello
        000E9B30
    */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *My initial assumption* It's well documented in [Notes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt)

Comment: *Why not invoke `std::ostream& std::ostream::operator<<(const void* val)`?* Because the non-member overload matches better.